# what should the default language that I load the Visual Studio IDE in?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008

THe fact that some of the code I am studying is writtne in C++ and some of it is written in C# is a condern.  Could it be that I need to step from one DLL written in C++ to another written in C#?  If so, what should the default language that I load the Visual Studio IDE in?

Answer (score 2):

Pick whatever one you're likely to use the most. Choosing C# for example doesn't mean you can't use Visual Studio for C++ projects. It just means that for example when you create a new project the C# project list will be the ones at the top. There are probably other subtle differences too (such as adding a new class etc to an existing project), but there's nothing major.

Answer (score 2):

The default language that you load Visual Studio has no bearing on the files you are able to edit or create in Visual Studio

All it does is setup the defaults for when you create a new project or class to automatically default to that language.

So I would say which ever language you are going to be using most would be the ideal choice.

Answer (score 0):

I Would personally use the C# as the start up.

Reason for this is that you can easily read C++ code, but if your writing an application in C#, it would easier to start VS in c#.